# invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, forward-declaration

This is my makefile file
all: trie

```
trie: trie.o main.o
    gcc trie.o main.o -o trie -std=c11 -g -Wall

trie.o: trie.c trie.h
    gcc -c trie.c -o trie.o -std=c11 -g -Wall

main.o: main.c trie.h
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o -std=c11 -g -Wall

clean:
    rm -f *.o trie
```

and header file

```
#ifndef TRIE_H
#define TRIE_H

struct node;
typedef struct node node;

//insert a word in a leaf
void insert(char* word, node* leaf);

#endif //TRIE_H
```

and trie.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "trie.h"

struct node {
  char* data;
  node* child[127];
};

void insert (char* word, node* leaf) {
  node* curr = leaf;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {//start from beginning of char to end
    if (curr == NULL) {
      curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // if it's null, creating new node
      curr->data = "";
    }
    curr = curr->child[(int) word[i]];
  }
  curr->data = word; // set last node stored the word
}
```

it occurs error message in the main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "trie.h"

int main() {
  node* x = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  insert("hi", x);
  return 0;
}
```

and this is error message:

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:35: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘node {aka struct node}’
   node* x = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

have any idea why my code has an error?

Comment: You can move your definition of `struct node` into the header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `main.c` doesn't have a definition of `node`, just a declaration of the name without defining the structure. You either need to include the definition in the `.h` file so both `trie.c` and `main.c` can see it, or you need to provide an allocator method (declared in `trie.h`, defined in `trie.c`) that can perform a definition aware allocation (and possibly initialization) of a `node` in a place that has access to the definition of the otherwise opaque type.

Comment: as you see my code, I declared struct node in trie.h file and defined in trie.c. and included trie.h in main and trie.c....

Comment: @CloeLee You have a *forward declaration* of `struct node` in `trie.h`.  However, the *definition* is necessary for `sizeof` to know how big that structure is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the Header files containing related structures.