# sizeof operator shows wrong size of struct in c

Tags: c, sizeof, void, incomplete-type

Having this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char c;
} foo;

void func(void *arg)
{
    printf("sizeof arg: %ld\n", sizeof(*arg));
}

int main()
{
    foo f = {6, 'c'};
    func(&f);

    printf("the real sizeof struct foo: %ld\n", sizeof(f));
}
```

output:

```
sizeof arg: 1
the real sizeof struct foo: 8
```

As you can see the function shows wrong result. If the reason is [invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904700/invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-incomplete-type), then why does it shows `sizeof arg: 1`? `void` is not `1` bytes long, but incomplete type, so why is this result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void

Comment: You are getting confused by a poorly thought out language extension that some practical joker with a wicked sense of humour decided to enable in GCC by default. My recommendation is to disable all language extensions. `-std=c11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic` is one way to do so.

Comment: Given `void *arg`, `sizeof( *arg )` is invalid code.  You can't dereference a `void *` pointer.

Answer (score 7):

You're attempting to get the size of `void` which the C standard doesn't allow.  However, some implementations define `sizeof(void)` to be 1 which is what you're seeing here.

The function has no way of knowing that the `void *` you passed it is actually a `foo *`.  You would need some other way of conveying that information.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
printf("sizeof arg: %ld\n", sizeof(*arg));
```

is incorrect. The expression `*arg` has the incomplete type `void`. You need to write

```
printf("sizeof arg: %ld\n", sizeof(* ( foo * )arg));
```

Early versions of C do not have the type `void`.  Instead the type `char` was used as the type `void`. As the `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1` then some compilers for backward compatibility with the old specifications of C set `sizeof( void )` to `1` though it is not correct from the C Standard's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The result *should* be a diagnostic, as `sizeof (void)` (which `sizeof (*arg)` resolves to) is a *constraint violation*:

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
> **Constraints**
> 1    The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
> incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
> designates a bit-field member. The `_Alignof` operator shall not be applied to a
> function type or an incomplete type.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

`void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed - you cannot create an object that type, so using `sizeof` on it is a coding error, full stop.

*However*, for some reason, certain implementations decided to have `sizeof (void)` evaluate to 1 unless you're in "pedantic" mode.   Obviously someone thought it was useful in some circumstances, but I wouldn't recommend its use.

Comment: For some strange reason, I can't quite connect "break the language (literally!) in a way that confuses new programmers" with "useful".

Comment: @AndrewHenle — take up the discussion with the GCC team (and, AFAIK, `clang` implements `sizeof(void) == 1` for compatibility with GCC).  OTOH, it is probably 20 years too late to affect the GCC decision; backwards compatibility means it is here in perpetuity.  See [Arithmetic on void and function pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).